# SQL Find names containing "ar"

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im new to SQL trying to figure it out.

Im trying to get first names from a table containing "ar"

this is what ive put

```
SELECT EMP_FNAME 
 FROM employee
where EMP_FNAME CONTAINS 'ar';
```

When I try to run it I get an error saying:

> Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'EMP_FNAME CONTAINS 'ar''.

What is the error in that line?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you mean `LIKE` and likely you are using `MS ACCESS` due to simlarity of the error message.

```
SELECT EMP_FNAME 
FROM   employee
WHERE  EMP_FNAME LIKE '*ar*';
```

- [MS Access LIKE operator](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php)

Answer (score 1):

If this is T-SQL (SQL Server), and you actually want to use CONTAINS then you may mean:

```
SELECT EMP_FNAME 
 FROM employee
 WHERE CONTAINS(EMP_FNAME, 'ar');
```

Otherwise, LIKE (MS ACCESS native):

```
SELECT EMP_FNAME 
 FROM employee
 WHERE EMP_FNAME LIKE '*ar*';
```

Or, LIKE (OLEDB, ANSI SQL):

```
SELECT EMP_FNAME 
 FROM employee
 WHERE EMP_FNAME LIKE '%ar%';
```

Answer (score 0):

For others, use % instead of * for wildcard

```
SELECT EMP_FNAME 
FROM   employee
WHERE  EMP_FNAME LIKE '%ar%';
```